# Php execute ssh git pull script without sudo (host verification error)

Tags: php, git, ssh

**What I am trying to do**

I have a git repository on bitbucket. After pushing to the repository from my local machine I want to automatically pull the master branch to my webspace.

**What I have done so far**

I connected to my server using ssh, created the ssh key and registered the public key on github.
I created a .sh script which pulls the master branch using ssh - so far so god - everything works when I run the script from the command line/putty

**What is the problem**

I want to trigger the .sh script with a webhook on bitbucket (I can give an url). For that purpose I created a .php file in my webspace:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('./deploy.sh 2>&1');
echo $output;
```

my .sh script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull git@bitbucket.org:dualmeta/test.git master
```

As already said, running the .sh script with putty works perfectly fine. However if I enter the url to the .php file in my browser it gives me an error:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I already did some reserach and found that many people have the exact same problem. However in my case i do not have root/sudo access because it is a rented webspace and not my own vServer.

Is there any chance getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You must add access www-data or apache user to your git directory.

```
chown -R apache:apache git_directory
```

or

```
chown -R www-data:www-data git_directory
```

or

```
chmod o+rw -R git_directory
```

Use this too :

```
git config credential.helper store
```

Comment: Probably I did something wrong but it did not work for me...
I used "chmod o+rw -R ." in my git directory where I want to pull the repo. 

"git config credential.helper store" and "git pull" did not do anything...

Comment: You should run "git config credential.helper store" as root user. for first time.

Comment: Apparently I can't run commands as root user (as described in my initial question)

Comment: Oh, I think you don't want to add php exec run as root & you have root access.